# Why doesn't this delegate work?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

In a console app, I have the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  var t = New Test();
  var newString = t.TestDelegate(tester("just testing"));

  public static string tester(string s) {
    return s;
  }
}

public delegate string MyDelegate(string s);

public class Test
{
  public string TestDelegate(MyDelegate m)
  {
    return "success!";
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. On the `var newString` line, I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'MyDelegate'

`tester` has the same signature as `MyDelegate`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `TestDelegate()` method requires an instance of `MyDelegate`. You are passing it a `string`. If you want to pass a delegate instance that refers to `tester`, then just pass `tester`, i.e. `var newString = t.TestDelegate(tester);`. If that's not what you want, then I have no idea what you want. Please fix your question so it makes sense.

Comment: How many letters are in an ordinary envelope?  One. How many letters are in "an ordinary envelope"? Eighteen. A function that produces a string, and the string it produces, are two very different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing delegate - you are passing result of `tester("just testing")` method execution (which is string):

```
t.TestDelegate(tester("just testing"))
```

If you want to pass delegate:

```
t.TestDelegate(tester);
```

Also you don't use passed delegate `m` in your `TestDelegate` method. You can do something like:

```
public string TestDelegate(MyDelegate m)
{
   return m("success!"); // m will be your tester method and you call it with success param
}
```

And you are declaring static method inside other method (but I believe it's just copy-paste typo).